# ¿Cómo reparto responsabilidades entre HTML y CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, diseño

Estoy trabajando en mi TFG y el otro día en mi entorno de trabajo nos surgió la siguiente duda.
Un compañero se encarga del entorno HTML puro, yo de proporcionarle estilos (CSS). El problema surgen cuando queremos colocar un boton que realicce cierta actividad al pasarle el ratón por encima.

**¿Quién se debería encargar de ello? ¿Yo con hover, o mi compañero con onClick?
¿Dónde colocarías los listeners?**

Tambien pensamos en la solución de "contratar" a un tercero especializado en JS o JQuery, que se encargara de estas tareas, pero el problema de esto surge al pensar que solo sería ese tercero el que tendría un crecimiento en un futuro, mientras que mi compañero y yo, al tener realizadas ya todas nuestras tareas de diseño, nos estancaríamos y por lo tanto seríamos despedidos.

Por supuesto, todas las ideas deben seguir el modelo de GRASP  (Alta cohesion, baja modularidad, responsabilidades)

**¿Qué idea os parece mejor o cual aportaríais nueva?**

PD: Sé que este tema solo recogerá opiniones, pero es eso lo que ando buscando ya que necesito diferentes puntos de vista para decidirme entre una cosa u otra.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: En mi opinión, si se puede realizar con CSS y es cosa del diseño, mejor no utilizar Javascript para ello.

Comment: Bienvenida, te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask], tu pregunta, si bien interesante,  lamentablemente recogerá mas que nada opiniones algo que no entra en el formato del sitio, por lo que eventualmente podría terminar cerrada. Suerte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La verdad no hay una regla que te prohíba hacer una cosa o la otra, así que esta es mi humilde opinión a tus preguntas:

**¿Quién se debería encargar de ello? ¿Yo con hover, o mi compañero con onClick? ¿Dónde colocarías los listeners?**

*si solo necesitas alterar el estilo del botón, se debería hacer con CSS, pero si necesitas que al hacer hover o click sobre el botón se muestre una nueva pantalla, se cargue una lista, o algo por el estilo, deberías usar javascript.
Por otro lado los listeners deberías estar en un tercer archivo, que solo contenga js, y este ser importado en el documento html*

---

**¿Qué idea os parece mejor o cual aportaríais nueva?**

*Si se están dedicando al frontend, primero deberían comenzar por establecer un diseño para todo su proyecto, crear los wireframes de las pantallas y formularios. Ya con eso tu compañero puede dedicarse a crear el código HTML y tu al mismo tiempo ir trabajando en el CSS, lo ideal es que usen algún software para manejar versiónes, como GIT.*

*Por el lado de javascript, mi recomendación es que lo hagan ustedes, aprendan y experimenten con él. pero procuren usar javascript para cosas que solo sean necesarias, traten de evitar utilizar javascript para temas de diseño.*

creo que es todo lo que les puedo decir